# Noob Python Q: Update to .py file not working - do I need to kill and nohup?

Tags: python

I've updated a python file on the server, but don't see that change reflected on the site.

Is it necessary to KILL _wsgi-0.1.py and then nohup to get the server to see the file updates.

(sorry I know this is likely painfully obvious, but I'm not a python guy - just need to make simple change to a file).

Comment: "on the server" - on what server? None of us know what your setup is. In any case this sounds like a sysadmin question, rather than a programming one. I suggest https://serverfault.com/ instead of Stack Overflow, but please read the guidance there on [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your question there.

Comment: sorry for likely mis-post. It's a web server running CentOS and python 2.7.16.  A few python scripts make up the backend that feeds the site.

Comment: What webserver - Apache, nginx, something else? Likely the solution to your problem is a "reload" command on the webserver, e.g. something like `sudo service apache2 reload`, so I suggest searching for those terms; the fact that it's Python seems largely irrelevant.

Comment: nginx. I did try reloading nginx but that seemed to have no affect.